# Send an email to one contact with multiple orders

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a question.

We have two Data Extensions. One for all Orders, where every Order ist linked with an Contact and a contact Data Extension.

Now we want to send an email to contact, with all orders (Orders are flats in this case) included. 
If we bring both data extensions to one, I don not know how to tell the Mail: Take all order with the same contact.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Thx and regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the assumption that you only want to send the email to contacts with at least one order I would suggest the following:

1. SQL Query: Left join Contacts to Orders on the Contact ID. The result is a data extension with all contacts that have at least one associated order. Only the fields from the contact data extension are necessary.
2. Ampscript in Email: Pull the order information from the orders data extension with LookupOrderedRows and then include the order information row by row (each is an order) with a for loop.

Both steps are not overly complicated codewise and also allow you to include qualification filters if needed (obviously making it a bit more complicated ;)).

Does that sound like it might fit your scenario?